# Expected "End" Code

Tags: vbscript

I am getting this error for the code below on the second to last line Char 13. I cannot see any problem with the code. Is someone able to help?

```vb
Function Results(KBname)
    Select Case Return
        Case 9009
            LogFile.WriteLine(Now & "  -  WARNING: " & KBname & " is already installed; skipping installation.")
        Case 2359302
            LogFile.WriteLine(Now & "  -  WARNING: " & KBname & " is already installed; skipping installation.")
        Case -2145124329
            LogFile.WriteLine(Now & "  -  WARNING: " & KBname & " is not required for this system; skipping installation.")
        Case Else
            LogFile.WriteLine(Now & "  -  Install of " & KBname & " has completed with return code: " & RETURN)
    End Select
End Function
```

Comment: To better diagnose the problem, please show some code.

Comment: What its the exact error you are getting?  Where is the value of "return" set?

Answer (score 3):

If is error code 800A03F6 it could mean an error related to an If-Then elsewhere (prior to this function) that wasn't properly closed.